# Where to find the pages and links shared on new Facebook profiles?

Tags: facebook

Facebook rolled the new Facebook profiles. In old Facebook the pages I "liked" and links that I "shared" are directly shown in profile pages, but in the new Facebook both are missing.

So, where I can find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the links that you have posted by clicking on **Links** on the left side of the home page (you may need to click **More▾** first, or just go to http://www.facebook.com/posted.php) and then click on **My Links**.

And as Jonik stated, you can find the pages you like on your profile **Info** tab.

Comment: "My Links" is not appearing when I click on "Links". How do we get this to view?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the pages you "like" in the Info tab (select "Info" in the menu below profile picture).

[image]

As for links you have shared, <s>I don't think there's other way to find those than by browsing your Wall.</s> **Edit**: Ah, fortunately I was wrong about this, as [mark4o points out](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12623/where-to-find-the-pages-and-links-shared-on-new-facebook-profiles/12632#12632)!